# Javascript: Make a cookie expire in 5 minutes

Tags: javascript, cookies

Could someone update the following code to make the cookie expire in 5 minutes.

```
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
if (days) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
}
else var expires = "";
document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
```

}

Comment: `date.setTime(date.getTime()+(5*60*1000));`

Comment: And what "days" parameters in code?

Comment: @ꜱᴜʀᴇꜱʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ I believe that would be 5 seconds.

Comment: @smarx Edited already. Good answer btw.

Answer (score 24):

Just edit the time argument to take minutes instead of days

```
function createCookie(name,value,minutes) {
    if (minutes) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(minutes*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    } else {
        var expires = "";
    }
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

createCookie("name", "value", 5)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*5*60*1000));
```

## Explanation:

The previous code was this:

```
date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
```

`days` is presumably the number of days, and then it's multiplied by 24 hours in a day, 60 minutes in an hour, 60 seconds in a minute, and 1000 milliseconds in a second.

So `days*24*60` was the number of minutes. Just put a `5` in there instead.

Comment: I like @adeneo's answer better, but my explanation may still be helpful, so I'm not deleting it.